# Is it possible to post on other user wall from my account using facebook api's

Tags: facebook, post

I have a requirement where i need to post to my webapp user's fb wall from my webapp fb account(After asking user permission). I have seen other examples where webapp post to the user's wall on behalf of user. In my case instead of posting on behalf of user i have to post from webapp fb account to user wall.

Is this case possible? If possible please provide me the details.

Thanks.

Comment: I believe this has been deprecated by facebook. You can only post on your own wall via the api

Answer (score 0):

As of February 6, 2013 Facebook has depreciated the feature to post to Friends wall. The same was announced in this [blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/10/10/growing-quality-apps-with-open-graph/).
If you want to allow people to post to their friend’s timeline from your app, you can invoke the [feed dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/).